# Is the function $\textbf {z} \mapsto \left (1 - |\textbf {z}|^2 \right )^{\lambda}$ integrable with respect to the volume measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> Is the function $\textbf {z} \mapsto \left (1 - |\textbf {z}|^2 \right )^{\lambda}$ defined on the open unit ball $\mathbb B^n$ of $\mathbb C^n$ integrable with respect to the normalized volume measure of $\mathbb B^n$ for $-1 \lt \lambda \lt \infty\ $?

I have done it for $n = 1$ and the value of the integral turns out to be $\frac {1} {1 + \lambda}.$ By looking at the formula for Jacobian for polar coordinates in $n$-dimension it turns out that the given function is integrable if and only if $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac {r^{2n - 1}} {(1 - r^2)^{\lambda}}\ dr \lt \infty$$ for $-\infty \lt \lambda \lt 1.$ Upon substituting $1 - r^2 = s$ the integral becomes $$\frac 1 2 \int_{0}^{1} s^{-\lambda} (1 - s)^{n-1}\ ds = \frac 1 2 \mathrm {B} (1 - \lambda, n)$$ which is finite since $\lambda \lt 1.$ Am I right with my argument?